# R nlsModel singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates error initial parameter estimation problem

Tags: r, non-linear-regression, nls

I need to do an nls fit for crop/year data (see [Question on nls fit in R - why is this such a strange fit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64977367/question-on-nls-fit-in-r-why-is-this-such-a-strange-fit/64977765#64977765)).

I am starting with this data and using the coefficients from a regular linear model fit as the initial parameter estimates.

```
x <- c(1979L, 1980L, 1981L, 1982L, 1983L, 1984L, 1985L, 1986L, 1987L, 
1988L, 1989L, 1990L, 1991L, 1992L, 1993L, 1994L, 1997L, 1998L, 
2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 2003L, 2004L, 2012L, 2014L, 2018L)

y <- c(94.4, 100, 120.6, 97.3, 110, 110, 80, 110, 117, 115, 50, 120, 
68.4, 137, 83, 106, 124, 113, 95.8, 115.7, 60, 105, 60, 74, 95.7, 
100)

mod_lm <- lm(y~x)
```

I am now getting this error with the minpack.lm package,

```
library(minpack.lm)

mod_nls <- nlsLM(y ~ a+x^b, start=list(a = mod_lm$coefficients[1],b=mod_lm$coefficients[2]))    

Error in nlsModel(formula, mf, start, wts) : 
 singular gradient matrix at initial parameter estimates
```

or this one, if I try the nls2 package.

```
library(nls2) 

mod_nls <- nls2(y ~ a+x^b, start=list(a = mod_lm$coefficients[1],b=mod_lm$coefficients[2]))

Error in numericDeriv(form[[3L]], names(ind), env) : 
 Missing value or an infinity produced when evaluating the model
```

I'm assuming the problem is poor initial parameter estimates.  How do I get to better parameter estimates initially?  Thank you.

Comment: I get the same error, but not when using `x <- 1:26`. Also it seems to work fine when using no starting parameters.

Comment: Your solution works fine (with one adjustment).  Anyway, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is that there is no strong relationship in your data:

```
cor(x, y)
# [1] -0.219275
cor(x, y, method="spearman")
# [1] -0.2145792
cor(x, y, method="kendall")
# [1] -0.117833
plot(y~x)
```

You can see from the correlations and the plot that there is a weak negative association between x and y. There is essentially no strong evidence that a nonlinear fit would be superior to the simple linear regression.
[image: Linear Regression]

The plot is one line of evidence and the rank correlations are another. If the relationship was a simple polynomial, then the Spearman and Kendall correlations would be larger than the Pearson correlation. As @Erik Krantz points out, letting the functions guess at the initial values (1, 1) works better than using the linear regression coefficients.

Here is a plot of the line described by your initial conditions compared to the data:

```
plot(x, coef(mod_lm)[1] + x^coef(mod_lm)[2], ylim=c(0, 1000), type="l")
points(x, y)
```

[image: Starting fit]

Just looking at the plot shows you that the first value is much too large and that a starting value around 100 would be better:

```
mod_nls <- nlsLM(y ~ a+x^b, start=list(a = 100, b = coef(mod_lm)[2]))
mod_nls
# Nonlinear regression model
#   model: y ~ a + x^b
#    data: parent.frame()
#       a     b.x 
# 98.1638 -0.1306 
#  residual sum-of-squares: 12142
# 
# Number of iterations to convergence: 13 
# Achieved convergence tolerance: 1.49e-08
```

Comment: Yes, I realize that in this situation a simple linear fit is fine, but I can't look at 1000's of these plots to determine this, so I need a way to automate it, accurately.

Comment: A first check could be to compare the Spearman/Kendall correlations to the Pearson.

Answer (score 0):

We can use nls2 to get an approximate fit and we see that it is nearly a horizontal line.  Using the coefficient for b shown below gives approximately x^b = 1 so the second term is constant and can be absorbed into `a` and we are just as well off using the model `y ~ a` and in this new reduced model `a` is estimated as `mean(y)`.  The point is that any sufficiently large negative value of `b` will give this result so the model is overparameterized and we can reduce it to just the `a` term.

```
library(nls2)

fm <- nls2(y ~ a + x^b, start = list(a = range(y), b = c(-10, 10)), alg = "brute")
fm
## Nonlinear regression model
##   model: y ~ a + x^b
##    data: parent.frame()
##      a      b 
## 99.714 -4.286 
##  residual sum-of-squares: 12179
##
## Number of iterations to convergence: 64 
## Achieved convergence tolerance: NA

plot(y ~ x)
lines(fitted(fm) ~ x, col = "red")
```

[image: screenshot]